# reload UITableViewCell after push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In *AViewController* there is a UITableView contains some data, call

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:bViewController animated:YES]`

to push *bViewController*, after doing some thing in *bViewController*, the cell selected in *aViewController* would change some info(for example update read count).

My solution:

1. add notification in *aViewController*
2. post notification in *bViewController* with parameter *(selected cell's indexPath)*
3. when get notification from *bViewController*, reload cell of indexPath.

now I meet this issue:
most of time there is no problem, but sometime the app would crash, the problem is
 **the cell in *aViewContrller* with indexPath(get from notification posted by bViewController)**is invisible**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the whole table view in viewDidAppeare method.
It will work every time you go back from bViewController.

Or just to keep performance in mind you can reload just visible rows:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Or even reload just one cell you made the changes, replace `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`  with array which contains one index path of the cell you want to reload.

Comment: yes I have thought about that, would that cause member problem? and if I selected the cell on the bottom, reload whole table would scroll to the top and the selected cell is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use NSNotifications for this - they are meant to be used in one to many relationship. In your case you better adopt [Delegate Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).

In addition you should not update table view which is not currently on screen, you better just update it's data, and when it comes visible again you call reloadData to make changes in data model visible to user.

Comment: yes I agree with you, but how to pass *indexPath* to *aViewCotroller* in viewWillAppear?

Comment: you can't in viewWillAppear, however if you make aViewController delegate of bViewController you can set some property of aViewController just before pop bViewController. Thus when viewWillAppear is called in aViewController you just check this property and use it as appropriate. By the way you might find useful isMovingFromParentViewController property to detect wheter viewWillAppear is called in a result of pop or in a result of itself being pushed/presented.